# VS Code How to prevent code from auto expand when the code are in commented state?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to disable the auto expand when code are commented ?
because is kind of frustating.

Or is there a way the collapsed the code that are in commented state ?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't collapse the commented code? What do you mean by auto expand? when does this happen

Comment: yes, i cannot collapse the commented code. this happen right now. or is there a way to collapse the commented code that i dont know?